# Are awaits in async method called without await still asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Consider the following code:

```
public static void Run() {
    DoStuffAsync();
}

public static async Task DoStuffAsync() {
     PerformCalc();
     await DoLongTaskAsync();
     PerformAnotherCalc();
}
```

Let's say I call `Run()`. I have a few questions regarding behaviour:

1. Will `PerformCalc()` be called synchronously on the same thread as the one that called `Run()`?
2. Will `DoLongTaskAsync()` be called asynchronously or synchronously? In other words, will/can `PerformAnotherCalc()` be called before `DoLongTaskAsync()` has finished?
3. Subsequently, can the `DoStuffAsync()` method return before execution of `DoLongAsyncTask()` has completed?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. It can (or will provided that `DoLongTaskAsync` is indeed asynchronous and returns an uncomplete task) *return* but not *complete*.

Comment: You can write a small test application and see for yourself. Calling a method that has async in its signature without await calling, is the same as if it didn't have async. Like any regular c# method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Async methods always *start* running synchronously. The magic happens at `await`, but only when `await` is given a `Task` that has not completed.

In your example, this is what will happen when you call `Run()`:

1. Jump to `DoStuffAsync()`
2. Jump to `PerformCalc()`
3. Jump to `DoLongTaskAsync()`
4. *If* `DoLongTaskAsync()` is a truly asynchronous operation and returns an incomplete `Task`, then `await` does its job and `DoStuffAsync()` returns an incomplete `Task` to `Run()`.
5. Since the task is not awaited, `Run()` completes.
6. When `DoLongTaskAsync()` completes, `DoStuffAsync()` resumes, and jumps to `PerformAnotherCalc()`.

All of that *can* happen on the same thread.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes. If it is an `async` method, it *might* end up going out and doing things on other threads. But it will start synchronously on the same thread.
2. `DoLongTaskAsync()` will be called asynchronously, but `PerformAnotherCalc()` will not be called before `DoLongTaskAsync()` finishes, because you used `await`.
3. Yes. This is how `await` works. It will return an incomplete `Task` (that is, only if `DoLongTaskAsync()` is truly asynchronous and returns an incomplete `Task`). Then once `DoLongTaskAsync()` finishes, execution of `DoStuffAsync()` resumes where it left off.

Comment: Good answer. A small note: Async methods always start running synchronously **relative to the caller**. This is important because if the caller is already running asynchronously, it will be synchronous to the caller but not necessarily to the caller that called the caller. Pretty sure this is what you meant but may help avoiding confusion.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Will PerformCalc() be called synchronously on the same thread as the one that called Run()?

Yes.

> 2. Will DoLongTaskAsync() be called asynchronously or synchronously? In other words, will PerformAnotherCalc() be called before DoLongTaskAsync() has finished?

It will be called synchronously, but it may return a `Task` before the "Long Task" operation has finished. Either way, the `Task` it returns is awaited, so `PerformAnotherCalc` will not be called until the `Task` returned from `DoLongTaskAsync` completes.

> 3. Subsequently, can the DoStuffAsync() method return before execution of DoLongAsyncTask() has completed?

The `DoStuffAsync` method will return when it hits the first `await` (iff the `Task` being awaited is pending). That's how `async` methods work -- they run synchronously up until the first `await` of a `Task` which is pending, and then they return a `Task` which will complete when the whole method has executed.

If might be that `DoLongTaskAsync` returns a `Task` which has already completed: in that case, `DoStuffAsync` won't return until `PerformAnotherCalc` has returned. If `DoLongTaskAsync` returns a `Task` which is still pending, then `DoStuffAsync` will return at that point, and it will return a `Task` which completes once the `Task` returned from `DoLongTaskAsync` has completed, *and* `PerformAnotherCalc` has returned.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No
3. Yes

Put otherwise, if you consider those methods:

```
public static void Run1() {
    DoStuffAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

public static async Task Run2() {
    await DoStuffAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

public static async Task DoStuffAsync() {
     PerformCalc();
     await DoLongTaskAsync();
     PerformAnotherCalc();
}
```

In `Run2`, you are guaranteed that "Done" will be displayed after `PerformAnotherCalc`. In `Run1`, "Done" will be displayed after `PerformCalc` but before `PerformAnotherCalc` (assuming that `DoLongTaskAsync` is actually asynchronous, which depends of its implementation).

Comment: You might check the comment below the code. Looks like you mix up his example and yours

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I was mixing both examples yes. Added the missing bit to my answer to make it easier to understand

Answer (score -1):

All calls are synchronous. It's the `await` that can be asynchronous if the returned awaitable is not complete.